# C# Excel Interop: can't read all data from excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm having some problem reading the date from an xlsx file, what I mean is that it doesn't read all the information in the cells, for example I have in a cell this information:

```
"4876112","3456151712","345627712","3125HPC21017500011","34131HPC210349014112","35134HPC210273008212"
```

and when I check to see the DataTable I only see this information in the rows

```
"4876112","3456151712","345627712",
```

this is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(input, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

string sheetname = "";

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet in workbook.Sheets)
{
    sheetname = sheet.Name;
    break;
}

string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", input);
string query = String.Format("select * from [{0}$]", sheetname);
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
tabela = ds.Tables[0];
```

I entered and Formated the cells of the Excel into text and worked fine. Can I programatically change all the cells format into text.
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you usel OleDB for reading excel data, when you already usse Interop for Excel? You can read data from from the "sheet".

Comment: Side note: Wouldn't `sheetname = workbook.Sheets[0].Name` be simpler (instead of `foreach` and `break`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the cells in your worksheet to be formatted as text you can simply do:

```
sheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@";
```

Comment: It is because this modifies the document. Are you closing the xls after using it? If this is the case you can close it without saving using: workbook.Close(false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

Answer (score 1):

Here's a skeleton of how Excel can be accessed using C#. It would be better to use C# 4.0 or newer as it has better COM interop.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...
//create objects
Excel.Application oXL;
Excel._Workbook oWB;
Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

oXL         = new Excel.Application();
oXL.Visible = false;
oWB         = oXL.Workbooks.Open(template_file);
oSheet      = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets[1];

//set cell values
oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "my value here";

//set formatting
oSheet.get_Range("A1", "A15").Font.Bold         = true;
oSheet.get_Range("A1", "A15").VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
oSheet.get_Range("A1", "A15").ColumnWidth       = 20;

//close 
oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Close();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);
```